# Kubernetes ingress-nginx gives 502 error (Bad Gateway)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster for which I want :
- 1 Load Balancer per cluster,
- Ingress rules to direct to the right namespace and the right service.

I have been following this guide : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes

My deployments:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-world
        image: IMAGENAME
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
          name: hello-world


---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bleble
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bleble
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bleble
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: bleble
        image: IMAGENAME
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
          name: bleble
```

the service of those deployments:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: hello-world-svc
spec: 
  ports: 
     -  port: 8080
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 8000
  selector: 
    app: hello-world
  type: NodePort

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: bleble-svc
spec: 
  ports: 
     -  port: 8080
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 8000
  selector: 
    app: bleble
  type: NodePort
```

My Load balancer:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
```

My ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: simple-fanout-example
  namespace : default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: internal-lb.aws.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /bleble
        backend:
          serviceName: bleble-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /hello-world
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-world-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

I've set up the Nginx Ingress Controller with this : kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.24.1/deploy/mandatory.yaml

I am unsure why I get a 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable for one service and one 502 for another... I would guess it's a problem of ports or of namespace? In the guide, they don't define namespace for the deployment...

Every resources create correctly, and I think the ingress is actually working but is getting confused where to go.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have tried using "Cluster" instead of "Local" in my LB, it returns 400 Not found

Comment: What command did you use to query your service?

Comment: @Fei which service exactly?

Comment: You mentioned that you are getting 503 / 502. How did you get it? Through browser / Curl / other commands?

Comment: Oh, I get those by browsing the lb address + /nameservice. And I get the same with curl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, use `externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster` instead of `Local`. You can gain some performance (latency) improvement by using `Local` but you need to configure those pod allocations with a lot efforts. You will hit 5xx errors with those misconfigurations. In addition, `Cluster` is the default option for `externalTrafficPolicy`.

In your `ingress`, you route `/bleble` to service `bleble`, but your service name is actually `bleble-svc`. please make them consistent. Also, you would need to set your `servicePort` to 8080 as you exposed 8080 in your service configuration.

For internal service like `bleble-svc`, `Cluster IP` is good enough in your case as it does not need external access.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello! Using Cluster instead of Local puts returns 400 Not found. Maybe because the ingress isn't configured correctly?

Comment: Did you try curl -H "Host: internal-lb.aws.com" http://${your_LB}/bleble

Comment: So the address I am using right now ( I haven't asked my department yet for the DNS name yet) is the internal load balancer address (internal-letternumbers-numbers.region.elb.amazonaws.com). The definite name would be using a subdomain we own.

Comment: I have just tried yes. the /bleble returns with the curl command 503 and the /hello-world returns 502

Comment: Ops. Sry I missed one really obvious place. Let me update my answer. But please switch to Cluster and give it a try.

Comment: Good catch on the svc! Didn't realise it myself. I've put it on cluster now.  Both give 502 Bad getaway now (better!), instead of the previous 404 not found

Comment: Glad to help! Would appreciate if you accept my answers for those questions you ask.

Answer (score 4):

Found it!
The containerPort in the Deployment were set to 8000, the targetport of the services as well, but the person who did the Dockerfile of the code exposed the port 80. Which was the reason it was getting the 502 Bad getaway!

Thanks a lot as well to @Fei who has been a fantastic helper!

Comment: This solution worked for me as well. Thanks for providing this solution.