# Kubernetes: path based only works with root

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster and currently use path based routing. I previously posted this thread, so all my configuration is on there: [Kubernetes: 502 (Bad getaway)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56474192/kubernetes-502-bad-getaway)

My ingress controller is from there: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.24.1/deploy/mandatory.yaml

Here is my ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: simple-fanout-example
  namespace : default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /bleble(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: bleble-svc
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /hello-world
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-world-svc
          servicePort: 8080
```

This works absolutly fine, until you try to go anywhere that is not the domain.com/bleble or domain.com/hello-world. The services need to refer to each other, and the uri they request is just domain.com, which obviously doesn't work because the service is at domain.com/nameoftheservice.

The 2 problems are :

- The service name is bleble, so we decided the path should be /bleble. I saw on this documentation (kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite) that adding (/|$)(.*) would allow rewrite. We want to use url as domain.com/bleble/swagger or domain.com/bleble/clients, ... But when we type those, it brings back to what was on /bleble
- I need bleble to get an info from hello-world. Right now, instead of going from domain.com/bleble to domain.com/hello-world, it goes from domain.com/bleble to domain.com. it seems to only be able to call the host name, and not the path.

I've tried doing a single ingress resource and have `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root : /bleble` but this doesn't seem to be working. I've tried the annotation as well `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /coretest`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you asking about service to service calls?  Or calls from outside your cluster.  Can you give an example of a path you'd be calling, what you'd expect to happen (what service should handle the request) and what is actually happening?

Comment: FWIW, `/bleble(/|$)(.*)` is a very weird regex; the `$` should always be the terminating character, but yours says "match /bleble, end of line, and then whatever comes after the end of the line"; perhaps you meant `/bleble(?:/(.*))$` and then change your rewrite-target to be `$1`?

Comment: The service name is bleble, so we decided the path should be /bleble. I saw on this documentation (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) that adding (/|$)(.*)  would allow rewrite. We want to have url as domain.com/bleble/swagger or domain.com/bleble/clients, ... But when we type those, it brings back to what was on /bleble

Comment: @frankd I am indeed asking about my first service needs an info from my service2. Right now, instead of going from domain.com/bleble to domain.com/hello-world, it goes from domain.com/bleble to domain.com. it seems to only be able to call the host name, and not the path. Plus it does what I just typed on the above comment

Comment: @shrimpy what is the nginx ingress controller version you are using? `kubectl exec -it $POD_NAME -- /nginx-ingress-controller --version`