# kubernetes ingress-nginx gives 502 error and the address field is empty

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am setting up kubernetes on a AWS environment using kubeadm. I have setup ingress-nginx to access the service on port 443. I have checked the service configurations which look good. I am receiving 502 bad gateway and also the Address field in ingress is empty.

Front end service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: voyager-configurator-webapp
  name: voyager-configurator-webapp
spec:
  ports:
    -
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
  selector:
    component: app
    name: voyager-configurator-webapp
  type: ClusterIP
```

Ingress yml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-resource
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - kubernetes-test.xyz.com
    secretName: default-server-secret
  rules:
  - host: kubernetes-test.xyz.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: voyager-configurator-webapp
          servicePort: 443
```

```
NAME                     CLASS    HOSTS                         ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
nginx-ingress-resource   <none>   kubernetes-test.xyz.com             80, 443   45m
```

What could be the issue here ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you install the nginx ingress controller by yourself?

Comment: Yes I installed it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your service is created in proper namespace - if not add namespace field in service definition. It is not good approach to add label called `name` with the same name as your service, instead you can use different one to avoid mistake and configurations problem.
Read more about selectors and labels: [labels-selectors](https://medium.com/@zwhitchcox/matchlabels-labels-and-selectors-explained-in-detail-for-beginners-d421bdd05362).

Your frontend service should look like that:

```
piVersion: v1
kind: Service
name: voyager-configurator-webapp
metadata:
  labels:
    component: app
    appservice: your-example-app
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
  selector:
    component: app
    app: your-example-app
  type: ClusterIP
```

Your ingress should look like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - kubernetes-test.xyz.com
        secretName: default-server-secret
  rules:
  - host: kubernetes-test.xyz.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: voyager-configurator-webapp
          servicePort: 443
```

**You have to define path to backend to with Ingress should send traffic.**

Remember that is good to follow some examples and instructions during setup to avoid problems and waste of time during debugging.

Take a look: [nginx-ingress-502-bad-gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56474192/kubernetes-ingress-nginx-gives-502-error-bad-gateway/56476759#56476759), [aws-kubernetes-ingress-nginx](https://medium.com/@Joachim8675309/adding-ingress-with-amazon-eks-6c4379803b2).

Comment: I have narrowed down the issue to some extent. The issue is ingress is not forwarding the traffic to the frontend service. The landing page for / path is a basic auth page. Could this be a issue ?

Comment: Ingress object publictly expose your web app. You can redirect traffic to whatever path you want to. In some scenarios the exposed URL in the backend service differs from the specified path in the Ingress rule. Without a rewrite any request will return 404. Set the annotation nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target to the path expected by the service. See: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, Still I am seeing a 502 bad gateway error whic is giving the nginx version. nginx controller is in a different namespace and all my other services were in the default namespace, I tried putting all of them in a single namespace, even that didn't help. Also output of command ```kubectl get ingress``` has a empty address field. Interpod communication is working and I am able to access the url by using the service IP by doing a curl. Only issue is I am not able to access the url from external world.

Comment: Can you try to set up targetPort to 80, rest will be the same - ordinary port field - 443 ? Also can you add provided in comment above information to your post which describe problem.